# Formula to compute an arcuate segment length

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

Considering the class:

```
public class Point3D
{

    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double DistanceTo(Point3D to)
    {
        double dX = Math.Abs(to.X - X);
        double dY = Math.Abs(to.Y - Y);
        double dZ = Math.Abs(to.Z - Z);
        return Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY + dZ * dZ);
    }

}
```

And the class:

```
public class Segment
{

    public Point3D From;
    public Point3D To;
    public double? Radius;

    public Segment(Point3D from, Point3D to, double? radius)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
        Radius = radius;
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            double straightLength = From.DistanceTo(To);
            if (Radius == null)
                return straightLength;
            if (Radius < straightLength/ 2d)
                throw new Exception();
            // Compute the arcuate segment length
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to compute the length of the arc (with `Radius`) passing through `From` and `To` 3D points.

Some help will be welcome!

Comment: A segment has an area, not a length. What do you actually mean? The Spherical Distance?

Comment: What is Radius and how does it impact on segment Length ?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the *arc length*?

Comment: A segment in the context of a sphere is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment). What you're talking about is an arc.

Comment: Unrelated: the `Math.Abs` in `DistanceTo` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesTriangle.html

```
straightLength / 2 = Radius * sin( 1/2 * angle)
```

Therefore:

```
angle = 2 * arcsin( straightLength / 2 / Radius)
```

and

```
arcLength = Radius * angle;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need help principally because of 3D context.

Comment: Well, the resulting triangle is 2D, so this still applies. Just plug in `straightLength` as calculated by your `DistanceTo` function, calculate the angle as above and multiply by the radius.

Comment: Do you think I have to rename my `Segment` class? If I rename it to `Arc`, this will be wrong when Radius will be null too.

Comment: @Alex what about a static class with two Methods `double Distance(Point3D from, Point3D to)` and `ArcLength(Point3D from, Point3D to, double radius)`?

Answer (score 0):

One more reference:
[from math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974178/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-2-vectors-in-3d-space-given-a-preset-function)

S=length of the arc = r*theta,
where r= radius and Cos(theta)=(dotproduct of 2 vectors)/(product of the modulus of those vectors)